# How to test if user can upload and download files in given port range

Tags: bash, scripting, proftpd

For shell script which installs a daemon I need to make sure that the newly created daemon user has the rights to use the port range that is needed for a daemon. How can I check this?

Comment: The script is not relevant to answer your question, right?

Comment: yup ...its just  a shellscript to to install proftpd...and add user..

Comment: I dont know the logic of my question ...thats the problem dude....

Answer (score 0):

Use `netstat /a /n` to find the first *free* port in the dynamic/private ports range: 49152-65535.